# NSData getBytes into a readable float

Tags: objective-c

How do you convert an NSData object into a readable float array? So I can basically pick a point within that array and get a value back? Currently, I have the following

```
NSData *depthData = [NSData dataWithBytes:depthFrame.depthInMillimeters
                                         length:depthFrame.width*depthFrame.height*4];
float z;
[depthImageData getBytes:&z length:sizeof(float)];
NSLog(@"%f", z);
```

But how would it be possible to convert to say

```
NSLog(@"%f",depthFloatArry[100])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking for.

If you're saying that `depthFrame.depthInMillimeters` is a byte buffer containing `depthFrame.width * depthFrame.height` `float`s, then you have a couple of options:

- If you're **sure** that the byte buffer is properly aligned so that each `float` starts at a memory location whose address is a multiple of 4 bytes, you can simply use a type cast:

  ```
  float *floatArray = (float*)depthFrame.depthInMillimeters;
  NSLog(@"%f", floatArray[anyIndexInRange]);
  ```

  This avoids `NSData` altogether.
- Otherwise, if the data isn't aligned or you need or already have the `NSData` for some other reason, you can do something like this to get many `float`s at once:

  ```
  size_t len = /* any value between 1 and depthFrame.width * depthFrame.height */;
  float floatArray[len];
  [depthData getBytes:floatArray length:sizeof(floatArray)]; /* or sizeof(float) * len */
  ```
- If you just wanted to get an arbitrary single float from the `NSData` rather than just the first one, you could do this:

  ```
  NSUInteger offset = desiredIndex * sizeof(float);
  float z;
  [depthData getBytes:&z range:NSMakeRange(offset, sizeof(z))];
  ```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to convert the `NSData` contents into a `NSArray` of `NSNumber` instances - note that you'll need to wrap the floats into a `NSNumber`, as `NSArray` can only hold objects.

```
@interface NSData(MyConversion)
- (NSArray<NSNumber *> *)toFloatsArray;
@end

@implementation NSData(MyConversion)
- (NSArray<NSNumber *> *)toFloatsArray {
    NSInteger capacity = self.length / sizeof(float);
    NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *parsedNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity];
    for(NSInteger i=0; i<capacity; i++) {
        float aFloat;
        [self getBytes:&aFloat range:NSMakeRange(i*sizeof(float), sizeof(float))];
        [parsedNumbers addObject:@(aFloat)];
    }
    return parsedNumbers;
}
@end
```

, which you can use it like this:

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *numbers = [depthImageData toFloatsArray];
NSLog(@"%f", numbers[100].floatValue);
// or
NSLog(@"%@", numbers[100]);
```